# Creating a postgres External table from a CSV file (comma separated) which has an email column with multiple email addressed separated by comma

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to create a postgres external table from a CSV file which has one of its column as email address and this column has multiple email addresses separated by comma. Since the delimited for the file is a comma, when creating an external table, it is not able to differentiate between the "," within a column from the "," between columns. The list of emails in the email column is enclosed in double quotes as well.
Is there a way to load it without changing the delimited for the entire file?

Comment: What did you try so far? Which version of PostgreSQL are you running?

Comment: ..and which programming language are you using, or do you want to use to create the SQL insert commands?

Answer (score -1):

It's standard practice with CSV to enclose fields between double quotes.
`COPY... CSV` will import this directly.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE email(id int, emails text);
COPY email FROM STDIN CSV;
```

```
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1,"abc@example.com,def@example.com"
>> \.
```

Result:

```
 select * from email ;
 id |             emails              
----+---------------------------------
  1 | abc@example.com,def@example.com
(1 row)
```